# Datepicker - Disable next 3 days if its friday past 11AM

Tags: jquery, datepicker

I got some trouble making an awesome feature for my datepicker. The things i want to do is:

- I want to disable the next 3 days if the current day is friday, and if its past 11AM.

  ```
  $('#datetimepicker').datepicker({
      format:'d/m/Y',
      formatDate:'Y/m/d', 
      dayNamesMin: ['Søn', 'Man', 'Tir', 'Ons', 'Tor', 'Fre', 'Lør'],
      monthNames: [ "Januar", "Februar", "Marts", "April", "Maj", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "December" ],
      monthNamesShort: [ "Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "Maj", "Jun", "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Okt", "Nov", "Dec" ],
      minDate: +1,
      beforeShow : function(){
          var dateTime = new Date();
          var hour = dateTime.getHours();
          if(hour  >= 11){
              $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+2" );
          }
      }
  });
  ```

I have been look around other examples on stackoverflow but nothing worked. So nows my time to try my luck!

Many thanks beforehand!

Comment: What is breaking with this existing jquery stuff?

Comment: This is working perfectly for disabling today and tomorrow if the time is past 11AM

Comment: Ok, but there is not different behavior for weekends?  Your function doesn't do any logic for the actual [day of the week](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current javascript function doesn't take the day of the week into account.  Just add some logic to also check that the current day is a Friday.

```
...
beforeShow : function(){
        var dateTime = new Date();
        var hour = dateTime.getHours();
        var dayOfWeek = dateTime.getDay(); //check the day of the week
        if(dayOfWeek == 5  &&  hour >= 11) {
            $(this).datepicker( "option", "minDate", "+2" );
        }
    }
```

Note that the [`getDay()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay) function returns the day of the week as an 0-indexed integer, with Sunday being 0, and Saturday being 6.  So `date.getDay() == 5` is a Friday.